# The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter

The argument type 'MaterialStateProperty?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.

```
answerColor: answerSelected
    ? answer['score']
        ? MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          Colors.green; 
      )`enter code here`
        : MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          Colors.red; 
      )
    : null,
```

Comment: can you create snippet code instead of a screenshot image.

Comment: Can you include more about `answerColor` and `answer['score']`

Answer (score 0):

your aswerColor is `Color` variable.Not `MaterialStateProperty<Color>`

```
answerColor : answerSelected
   ? answer['score']
        ? Colors.green
        : Colors.red
   : Color.what ever color you want.
   // because its non-null value, you cant set null value
```

Comment: you missed the answer text

Comment: what do you mean the answer text?

Comment: no its okay, I missunderstood that

Comment: is it solve your issue?

Comment: no tha issue is solved now but its having new oness now

Comment: i didnt get it. issu is solved. which is your question is answered?